# Apply defaults to namespaced ActiveRecord translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

I have some models with a price attribute, which I want to translate.

In my locales file, I have this translation:

```
de:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      defaults:
        price: Preis
```

This works for any non-namespaced model, e.g.:

```
Shoe.human_attribute_name(:price) # works!
```

However, it doesn't work for namespaced models, e.g.:

```
Product::Shoe.human_attribute_name(:price) # doesn't translate!
```

Is it possible to keep the translation file DRY and apply the defaults to namespaced models as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `namespace/model` in your i18n file like this:

```
de:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      product/shoe:
        price: Preis
```

Comment: Do I have to add explicit translations for every namespaced model?

Comment: I believe so. The i18n key for the namespaced ones is different from the non-namespaced ones.